# Hide Edit with IntelliJ IDEA in windows explorer

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, windows-explorer

In my Windows explorer, I have the option to open files with the IntelliJ IDEA as shown in the screenshot below. Is there a way to hide / disable this?

[image: Edit with IntelliJ IDEA in Windows Explorer]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove it by deleting the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with IntelliJ IDEA
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the the solution for me